# VHDL Concurrent Array Assignment - Memory Structure gets wiped

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, vivado

I've been wrestling with a rather large project and I've come to an impasse, the following code simulates and works as expected *except* that it reassigns all memory addresses to UU upon a signal assignment. The code describe a fully descending stack with integrated stack pointer. I'm trying to avoid process statements for timing purposes and I would really like the memory block to remain a signal array (and not a variable array) for debugging purposes.

The selected address data must be present upon the rising clock edge (immediately) and must be completely stored and ready for re-reading no later than the falling edge of the same clock signal.

Maybe I've just been staring at my description for too long, but I don't understand why it's reassigning every value to UU when I write to a single address. There's definitely a VHDL rule I'm breaking here. I would like both an asynchronous reset to clear the entire array, as well as a synchronous read/write. If advisable, I would like to eventually remove the clock dependency altogether.

Here's the relevant code block:

```
-- Fully Descending Stack with integrated Stack Pointer --

LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

ENTITY STACK IS

GENERIC(
    BIT_WIDTH : INTEGER := 10;
    BIT_DEPTH : INTEGER := 5
);
PORT(
    CLK                   : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    CE                    : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    RESET                 : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    LOAD                  : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    PUSH                  : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    POINTER_WRITE_ADDRESS : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(BIT_DEPTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);
    STACK_DATA_IN         : IN  std_logic_vector(BIT_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);
    -- OUTPUT SIGNALS --
    POINTER_ADDRESS       : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(BIT_DEPTH - 1 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
    STACK_DATA_OUT        : OUT std_logic_vector(BIT_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
    STACK_FULL            : OUT STD_LOGIC                                := '0';
    STACK_EMPTY           : OUT STD_LOGIC                                := '1'
);
END STACK;
ARCHITECTURE Behavioral OF STACK IS

CONSTANT STACK_DEPTH : INTEGER := (2**BIT_DEPTH) - 1;

SUBTYPE WORD_SIZE IS std_logic_vector(BIT_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);
TYPE MEMORY IS ARRAY (STACK_DEPTH DOWNTO 0) OF WORD_SIZE;

SIGNAL STACK_MEMORY   : MEMORY  := (OTHERS => (OTHERS => '0'));
SIGNAL STACK_POINTER  : INTEGER := STACK_DEPTH;

BEGIN
STACK_MEMORY <= (OTHERS => (OTHERS => '0')) WHEN RESET = '1' ELSE
                (to_integer(unsigned(POINTER_WRITE_ADDRESS)) => STACK_DATA_IN) WHEN LOAD = '1' AND rising_edge(CLK) ELSE
                ( STACK_POINTER  => STACK_DATA_IN) WHEN (PUSH = '1' AND CE = '1' AND NOT (STACK_POINTER = 0)) AND rising_edge(CLK);

STACK_POINTER <= (STACK_POINTER + 1) WHEN PUSH = '0' AND CE = '1'AND NOT(STACK_POINTER = STACK_DEPTH) AND rising_edge(CLK)ELSE
                 (STACK_POINTER - 1) WHEN PUSH='1' AND CE = '1' AND NOT (STACK_POINTER = 0) AND rising_edge(CLK);

STACK_EMPTY  <= '1' WHEN STACK_POINTER = STACK_DEPTH else '0';
STACK_FULL   <= '1' WHEN STACK_POINTER = 0 else '0';

STACK_DATA_OUT  <= STACK_MEMORY(STACK_POINTER+1) WHEN CE = '1' AND PUSH='0' AND (NOT(STACK_POINTER = STACK_DEPTH)) ELSE 
                   STACK_DATA_IN WHEN LOAD='1' or (CE = '1' AND PUSH='1' AND 
NOT(STACK_POINTER = 0))ELSE
                   (OTHERS => '0') WHEN (STACK_POINTER = STACK_DEPTH);

POINTER_ADDRESS <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(STACK_POINTER, 
POINTER_ADDRESS'length));
END Behavioral;
```

------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------

Okay, I've taken a look at some reference material and rewritten my code as follows:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

ENTITY STACK IS

GENERIC(
    -- DATA STORAGE GENERICS --
    BIT_WIDTH : INTEGER := 10;
    BIT_DEPTH : INTEGER := 8
);
PORT(
    -- NON-SPECIFIC INPUT SIGNALS --
    CLK                   : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    CE                    : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    RESET                 : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    -- STACK OPERATION INPUT SIGNALS --
    LOAD                  : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    PUSH                  : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    POINTER_WRITE_ADDRESS : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(BIT_DEPTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);
    STACK_DATA_IN         : IN  std_logic_vector(BIT_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);
    -- OUTPUT SIGNALS --
    POINTER_ADDRESS       : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(BIT_DEPTH - 1 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
    STACK_DATA_OUT        : OUT std_logic_vector(BIT_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
    STACK_FULL            : OUT STD_LOGIC                                := '0';
    STACK_EMPTY           : OUT STD_LOGIC                                := '1'
);
END STACK;
ARCHITECTURE Behavioral OF STACK IS

CONSTANT STACK_TOP : INTEGER := (2**BIT_DEPTH) - 1;

SUBTYPE WORD_SIZE IS STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(BIT_WIDTH - 1 DOWNTO 0);
TYPE MEMORY IS ARRAY (STACK_TOP DOWNTO 0) OF WORD_SIZE;

SIGNAL STACK_MEMORY : MEMORY := (OTHERS => (OTHERS => '0'));

SIGNAL STACK_POINTER       : INTEGER := STACK_TOP;
SIGNAL STACK_POINTER_INPUT : INTEGER := 0;

BEGIN
STACK_POINTER_INPUT <= to_integer(unsigned(POINTER_WRITE_ADDRESS));
POINTER_ADDRESS     <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(STACK_POINTER, POINTER_ADDRESS'length));

STACK_POINTER_CONTROL : PROCESS(CLK)
BEGIN
    IF (Rising_Edge(CLK)) THEN
        IF (RESET = '1') THEN
            STACK_POINTER <= STACK_TOP;
        ELSIF (LOAD = '1') THEN
            STACK_POINTER <= STACK_POINTER_INPUT;
        ELSIF (CE = '1' AND PUSH = '0' AND STACK_POINTER < STACK_TOP) THEN
            STACK_POINTER <= STACK_POINTER + 1;
        ELSIF (CE = '1' AND PUSH = '1' AND STACK_POINTER > 0) THEN
            STACK_POINTER <= STACK_POINTER - 1;
        END IF;
    END IF;

END PROCESS STACK_POINTER_CONTROL;

BLOCK_MEMORY_CONTROL : PROCESS(CLK)
BEGIN
    IF (Rising_Edge(CLK)) THEN
        IF (RESET = '1') THEN
            STACK_MEMORY <= (OTHERS => (OTHERS => '0'));
            -- POP | Erase data from popped address --
        ELSIF (CE = '1' AND PUSH = '0') THEN
            STACK_MEMORY(STACK_POINTER) <= (OTHERS => '0');
            -- PUSH | Write data to stack pointer --
        ELSIF (CE = '1' AND PUSH = '1') THEN
            STACK_MEMORY(STACK_POINTER) <= STACK_DATA_IN;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END PROCESS BLOCK_MEMORY_CONTROL;

STACK_DATA_OUT <= (OTHERS => '0') WHEN RESET = '1'
    ELSE STACK_DATA_IN WHEN STACK_POINTER = 255
    ELSE STACK_MEMORY(STACK_POINTER + 1);

STACK_EMPTY    <= '1' WHEN STACK_POINTER = STACK_TOP else '0';
STACK_FULL     <= '1' WHEN STACK_POINTER = 0 else '0';

END Behavioral;
```

It now seems to operate correctly in all simulation tests, but I'm worried about timing conflicts between states. Is there a better way to improve upon this design?

Comment: There are a misconceptions in your narrative. Concurrent signal assignment statements are elaborated into process statements containing equivalent assignment statements, there's no downside to using process statements here. `(to_integer(unsigned(POINTER_WRITE_ADDRESS)) => STACK_DATA_IN)` is not a value of the subtype of MEMORY. (There's only one element in that aggregate, there are STACK_DEPTH + 1 elements in MEMORY). A tool issue? Write an equivalent process statement for state_memory using simple signal assignment. You'll see the error immediately. Think indexed names.

Comment: Actually, that's really helpful thank you. I wouldn't say it's necessarily a lack of information about the topic, but I've never had it explained well enough to conceptualize the differences between processes and concurrent statements. I honestly thought I was doing something "more efficient" than process statements based on what I've learned so far. Is there any benefit to my method or any real difference between concurrency and processes? What if I remove the clock edge statements?

Comment: You can increment pointers wtihout a clock.  You can get a simulation to work but in silicon it's a gated oscillator.

Comment: This is what your stack_memory assignment looks like, you can see only the aggregate for the reset matches MEMORY https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1fuM.jpg. The second two assignments should be indexed names.

Comment: "The selected address data must be present upon the rising clock edge (immediately) and must be completely stored and ready for re-reading no later than the falling edge of the same clock signal. " Use a clock rate multiplier (DLL, PLL or DCM) and design around clocked memories, so your synthesis tools can implement it as BlockRam. Otherwise it'll be slow and very expensive in LUT resources.

Comment: You should not edit you question to ask a new question: nobody will see it. Instead open a new topic. HOWEVER "... I'm worried about ..." is not a good question. It is [off topic for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) actually. Please show an actual error.

Comment: p.s. `IF (RESET = '1') THEN STACK_MEMORY <= (OTHERS => (OTHERS => '0'));` will not synthesize to block RAM. You cannot 'reset' a RAM: you need to write zeros to every address if you really want to clear it.